# Appending children to single parent node in xml using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

Thanks for the reply. There is a slight change in the requirement. 
The given xml structure is:

```
<A id=1>
<b>data1</b>
</A>
<A id=1>
<b>data2</b>
</A>

<A id=2>
<b>data1</b>
</A>
<A id=1>
<b>data3</b>
</A>
<A id=2>
<b>data5</b>
</A>
```

The resultant xml should be:

```
<A id=1>
<b>data1</b>
<b>data2</b>
<b>data3</b>
</A>
<A id=2>
<b>data1</b>
<b>data5</b>
</A>
```

Kindly let me know, how can i achieve this.
Thanks in advance.

I have an xml structure like the follwing:

```
<A>
<a1></a1>
</A>
<A>
<b1></b1>
</A>
<A>
<c1></c1>
</A>
```

I want the resultant xml as:

```
<A>
<a1></a1>
<b1></b1>
<c1></c1>
</A>
```

Can anyone help me to achieve this using xslt.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your current XSLT so far?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 2):

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="A[1]">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node() | following-sibling::A/node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="A[position() &gt; 1]"/>
```